# R: combinatorial string replacement

Tags: string, r, gsub

I am on the lookout for a gsub based function which would enable me to do combinatorial string replacement, so that if I would have an arbitrary number of string replacement rules

```
replrules=list("<x>"=c(3,5),"<ALK>"=c("hept","oct","non"),"<END>"=c("ane","ene"))
```

and a target string

```
string="<x>-methyl<ALK><END>"
```

it would give me a dataframe with the final string name and the substitutions that were made as in

```
name                x        ALK     END
3-methylheptane     3        hept    ane
5-methylheptane     5        hept    ane
3-methyloctane      3        oct     ane
5-methyloctane      5        ...     ...
3-methylnonane      3
5-methylnonane      5
3-methylheptene     3
5-methylheptene     5
3-methyloctene      3
5-methyloctene      5
3-methylnonene      3
5-methylnonene      5
```

The target string would be of arbitrary structure, e.g. it could also be `string="1-<ALK>anol"` or each pattern could occur several times, as in `string="<ALK>anedioic acid, di<ALK>yl ester"`

What would be the most elegant way to do this kind of thing in R?

Comment: How do you know that x = 3 means "hept" and "ane" in teh first line?  Are they all in order?

Comment: The order doesn't matter for me - but I assumed in this case that one would loop first over the vals in <x>, then over the vals in <ALK> and then over the vals in <END>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
d <- do.call(expand.grid, replrules)

d$name <- paste0(d$'<x>', "-", "methyl", d$'<ALK>', d$'<END>')
```

**EDIT**

This seems to work (substituting each of these into the `strplit`)

```
string = "<x>-methyl<ALK><END>"
string2 = "<x>-ethyl<ALK>acosane"
string3 = "1-<ALK>anol"
```

Using Richards regex

```
d <- do.call(expand.grid, list(replrules, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
names(d) <- gsub("<|>","",names(d))

s <- strsplit(string3, "(<|>)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]

out <- list()

for(i in s) {
  out[[i]] <- ifelse (i %in% names(d), d[i], i)
}

d$name <- do.call(paste0,  unlist(out, recursive=F))
```

**EDIT**

This should work for repeat items

```
d <- do.call(expand.grid, list(replrules, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
names(d) <- gsub("<|>","",names(d))

string4 = "<x>-methyl<ALK><END>oate<ALK>"

s <- strsplit(string4, "(<|>)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
out <- list()
for(i in seq_along(s)) {
  out[[i]] <- ifelse (s[i] %in% names(d), d[s[i]], s[i])
}
d$name <- do.call(paste0,  unlist(out, recursive=F))
```

Comment: Ha that's perfect - in only two lines - congrats for that and thx for the help!!

Comment: Ha sorry accepted this answer too soon perhaps - ideally I would like target string to be of an arbitrary structure, e.g. it could also be string="<x>-ethyl<ALK>acosane", and then the trick would be to insert the -ethyl and acosane in this case in the right columns in dataframe d. Any thoughts?

Comment: Many thanks - this one doesn't seem to work for cases where each pattern occurs several times though, e.g. string="<x>-methyl<ALK><END>oate<ALK>" as then line s <- strsplit(string, "(?<=l|\\>)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]  then gives "<x>"       "-methyl"   "<ALK>"     "<END>"     "oate<ALK>" (last element here should have been split). Any thoughts?

Comment: Ha thanks so much for all the effort - last solution works perfectly!!! Thx so much! Should definitely read up on those regular expressions...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not exactly sure we can even produce a "correct" answer to your question, but hopefully this helps give you some ideas.

Okay, so in `s`, I just split the string where it might be of most importance. Then `g` gets the first value in each element of `r`.  Then I constructed a data frame as an example.  So then `dat` is a one row example of how it would look.

```
> (s <- strsplit(string, "(?<=l|\\>)", perl = TRUE)[[1]])
# [1] "<x>"     "-methyl" "<ALK>"   "<END>"  
> g <- sapply(replrules, "[", 1)
> dat <- data.frame(name = paste(append(g, s[2], after = 1), collapse = ""))
> dat[2:4] <- g
> names(dat)[2:4] <- sapply(strsplit(names(g), "<|>"), "[", -1)
> dat
#              name x  ALK END
# 1 3-methylheptane 3 hept ane
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - I'll have a further think based on this. Problem I see is that it would only work for my 1st example, but not for the general case where the methyl wouldn't have to be inserted in the 2nd column, e.g. when there were more than 2 parts of the string not contained between < >

Comment: Well yes, it's very general because I don't have proper data.  With proper data, I would know what and where to index. But we can construct a useful function from it for sure.

Comment: Stole your regex - hope thats ok :)

Comment: No worries.  I also borrowed it from an earlier post.